# How to Store JSON Object in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am taking below request via my API :

```
{

   "Person" : {
        "name" : "abc",
        "age"  : "12",
        "hobby" : {
             "x" : "y"
             "z" : "d",
         }, 
        "other" : "abc"  
      }, 
    "attribute": "1",
    "attribute2": "2"


}
```

How i to store the Person object in code , since person object can contains any number of fields so the schema is not fixed, how i can store this as HashMap so i can do some processing.
My Code :

```
public class ApiRequest {


    private Map<String, Object> Person;
    private int attribute;
    private int attribute2;

}
```

What the correct to process person ?

Comment: Please specify, which json library you are using. Also what exactly is not working with your code? Aside from non-matching case of `person` property, which is easily fixed, it looks fine at first glance.

Comment: `Person` object is coming null for me

Comment: Ok, and the json library - gson, jackson, something else? If we can't reproduce the issue, we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ApiRequest, use JsonNode.

```
package com.example.demo.controller;import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;@RestController
public class DemoController {
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/ping",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public JsonNode index(@RequestBody JsonNode jsonNode) {
    System.out.println("Received JSON:"+jsonNode.toString());
    return jsonNode;
    }
}
```